How to get Menustyle for Views in SwiftUI Without using Menu?
I have an status menu that uses NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength). I am porting a MenuBarExtra that has many Views and state attributes. I want to avoid using NSMenuItem due to an ObservedObject I depend on inside the SwiftUI view I am porting. The status menu itself is managed by an class StatusItemManager: ObservableObject.
let statusItem: NSStatusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
...
let statusMenuContent = NSHostingView(rootView: MyViewWithButtons())
statusMenuContent.frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
menuItem.view = statusMenuContent
menu.addItem(menuItem)

This is the "gist" of it but I can post more code. This is more of a knowledge question about whether SwiftUI provides something to do what I'm asking or if I have to do it the manual way using menu.addItem for each View I have.
What I see:

What I want (previous behaviour using MenuBarExtra).

If I do
// inside MyViewWithButtons
var body: some View {
    Menu("") {
        // rest of views
    }
}

I get the following undesired behaviour:


You don’t need NSMenu.
Wrap your MyViewWithButtons body in SwiftUI’s Menu, everything will have a menu style.
struct MyViewWithButtons: View {

// your existing code 

    var body: some View {
        Menu("SBApp") {
             // your existing view code
        }
    }
}


I've already tried that. I want to avoid the dropdown in the popover. I've updated the question to show what happens if I do that.
